# Concat pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to concat without column names?

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1], 'col2': [4]})
>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([[5,5]])

>> pd.concat([df, df1])

    col1    col2    0       1
0   1.0     4.0     NaN     NaN
0   NaN     NaN     5.0     5.0
```

Also the types changed into `float64` from `int64` if you see closely.

Expected

```
    col1    col2
0   1        4
0   5        5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create same columns names in both DataFrames by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
```

Or assign columns names:

```
df1.columns = df.columns
#alternative - got 0,1 columns
#df.columns = df1.columns
```

Last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) with that of `df` on `df1`:

```
pd.concat([df, df1.set_axis(df.columns, axis=1)], ignore_index=True)
```

*NB. [`append` is being deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35407), don't use it.*

output:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     5     5
```